# How to capitalize first character of each sentence a paragraph using javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, uppercase

How do I capitalize the first letter of each sentence in a paragraph?

"this is test case. i want to capitalize first letter of each row using javascript. hello? i am talking!" => "This is test case. I want to capitalize first letter of each row using javascript. Hello? I am talking!"

Comment: Split each sentences. Replace them by adding an uppercase to the first letter. Join

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can utilize regex to achieve it:

```js
/(?<=(?:^|[.?!])\W*)[a-z]/g
```

```js
const text = 'this is test case. i want to capitalize first letter of each row using javascript. lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. "voluptas, debitis?" unde, delectus pariatur, velit vero "dolorem repellendus" veritatis. quia odio... aperiam (nemo) sint natus 0.1 hic ad nisi id magni praesentium.';

const result = text.replace(/(?<=(?:^|[.?!])\W*)[a-z]/g, i => i.toUpperCase());

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve the same behaviour using CSS `::first-letter` pseudo selectors:

```css
p::first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase
}
```

```html
<p>my name is Donald.</p>
<p>i live in Duckburg.</p>
<p>my best friend is Mickey.</p>
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but I want to do this by using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert in the below way.

```
let convertedText=text.split(".").map((s)=>{return s[0].toUpperCase() + s.slice(1)}).join(".");
```

Comment: Only works for periods, but not question marks, exclamations, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capitalize the first letter of each sentence, you can begin by splitting the string by the period.

```
const string = "this is test case. i want to capitalize first letter of each row using javascript."
const array = string.split('. ')
const newArray = [];
array.forEach(sentence => { newArray.push(sentence.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + sentence.slice(1)) })
newString = newArray.join('. ')
```

Capitalize the first letter of each sentence, then join the sentences with a period.

Comment: `"are there some cases this won't work? yes there are! oh I should fix it then"`

Comment: Yes, there are definitely other cases that you have to consider. I have just provided the basic logic to get started.